Is this counterargument to the claim that "Adi Sankara was a Vaishnavite" correct?
There is a semi-legendary biography of him in which he was supposedly saved by Narasimha from a Kapalika.  He is alleged to have composed "Bhaja Govindam" and other devotional works to Vishnu.
(1) In Advaita - Vishnu is part of Maya, same as all other deities and cannot simply be perceived in the Advaitic state of liberation. All his advocacy for Advaita contradicts his alleged Vaishnavism.  Did he ever advocate Vishnu-Bhakti and/or Vishnu-centric theology instead of Advaita Vedanta in his philosophical debates?
(2) If he didn't, all the devotional works attributed to him are just part of bhakti to his Ishta-devata(s) and are not central to his teachings.
